# rake not seeing Rails.application.secrets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

**In short:**

1. seems that rake does not have access to `Rails.application.secrets` in `config/database.yml` file
2. what is the purpose of `config/secrets.yml` then?

**In long:**

When I run

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

I get the error `Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`, though I specified appropriate values in `config/database.yml` and the user connecting should not be 'root'. This is an excerpt from respective config files:

```
# config/database.yml
production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:name] %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:username] %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:password] %>

# config/secrets.yml
production:
  secret_key_base: very-long-blah-blah-blah
  database:
    name: app_db_name
    username: app_db_user
    password: app_db_password
```

Seems that `rake` has no access to `Rails.application.secrets`. Running migration succeeds when I explicitly put necessary values in `database.yml`, for example, as follows:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:name]  || 'app_db_name' %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:username] || 'app_db_user' %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:password] || 'app_db_password' %>
```

The above proves that `Rails.application.secrets[:database][:name]` resolves to nothing.

How to have access to `Rails.application.secrets` in `rake`? Would this be the correct solution?

I know that I can use `ENV[VARNAME]` to fill in secret sections of `config/database.yml`. But what the the purpose of `config/secrets.yml` file then?

Moreover, I am using Passenger, which means that variables in `.bashrc` will probably not be accessible to the web server (I had this issue with `secret_key_base`). Therefore I try to avoid using environment variable. Just do not want to have all my secrets spilled all over the server.

rails-4.2.2, Ubuntu LTS 14.04

Comment: Don't think this is the entirety of your problem but you have the production host set as localhost. What does your production config look like on the server? I know you're not using heroku but what is the equivalent of running `heroku config`?

Comment: Passenger has no issues with environment variables set in `.bashrc`

Comment: @toddmetheny, what is wrong with having `localhost`? the application and the database are running on the save server and, in my understanding, the app is allowed to connect to the database as 'app_db_user'@'localhost' using mysql socket.

Comment: @j-dexx, yes, you are right. looks like I had made a mistake in my previous experiments. `.bashrc_profile` is read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen such ***nested content*** for the `secrets.yml` like you have, also the [**release notes**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml) doesn't have such kind. You should be just fine with the below code

```
# config/secrets.yml
production:
  secret_key_base: very-long-blah-blah-blah
  name: app_db_name
  username: app_db_user
  password: app_db_password
```

And in the `database.yml`

```
# config/database.yml
production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: <%= Rails.application.secrets.name %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.secrets.username %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.secrets.password %>
```

Comment: thank you. this works and looks simpler. I am paying the price of following someones recipe found in internet :(

Comment: When i pass adapter from the secrets.yml, It throws this error

    Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)